# Highlight words inside of input textarea

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, textarea

I need to create a input textarea that recognize words from the array of words in this.state and highlight the words while the user type the text:

expected results:

the array of words:
 [image]

the input textarea:
[image]

the code with array

```js
const arrOfWords = ["disposition", "distress", "vex", "governess", 'intimacy', 'footing', 'unreserve', 'intellectual', 'solitude']
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/brianmearns/pen/YVjZWw

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't change the style of a word in a `textarea` (meaning you can only apply that style to the *whole* content). Must `textarea` be used or can a `div` with the attribute `contenteditable` set to true also a viable element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change the style dynamically of a text area input.

However, a possible workaround is to display the text the user is writing below the text area. In that way the text will dynamically change as the user is writing and you can apply the specific styling for that array of words. 
You could even set the text area to not display the text and in that way the user would only see its input below with the right feature.